# unexpected token in seemingly valid statement

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting `unexpected token ||` in the example below ?

```
function isTriangle(a,b,c) {
  if ((a < c/2) && (b < c/2)) || ((b < a/2) && (c < a/2)) || ((c < a/2) && (b < a/2)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap all these conditions in a bracket

```
function isTriangle(a,b,c) {
  if ( ( (a < c/2) && (b < c/2) ) || ( (b < a/2) && (c < a/2) ) || ( (c < a/2) && (b < a/2) ) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

as you need to have a parent bracket which has all the conditions inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript requires `if (condition)` - count your parenthesis - you have `if (a) || (b) || (c)` which is different.

```
function isTriangle(a,b,c) {
  return ((a < c/2) && (b < c/2)) || ((b < a/2) && (c < a/2)) || ((c < a/2) && (b < a/2))
 }
```